# SSIS - use stored variable in final OLE DB Destination step

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I don't have much SSIS experience, however, I like to use a variable that gets assigned in the `Execute SQL Task` step in the `ole DB Destination` step. I guess a bit like a scalar.

Any pointers would be good. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Derived Column task in your Data Flow you can add in your filename variable as an additional column and then use it to map to your destination.